# Stunnel certificate verify failed

Tags: redis, stunnel

I am trying to setup stunnel with REDIS in windows.After installing stunnel and redis, I have following configuration fro server and client mode :

Client Machine Configuration:

```
[redis-stunnel]
client = yes
cert = stunnel.pem
accept = 127.0.0.1:6379
connect = 172.30.12.28:6390
verifyChain = yes
CAfile = stunnel.pem
checkHost = 172.30.12.28:6390
OCSPaia = yes
```

Server Machine configuration :

```
[redis-stunnel-server]
accept  = 6380
connect = 6379
cert = stunnel.pem
```

Configuration is loading successfully, But when i try to connect from client machine to the port number :6379, I am getting the following error :

```
Service [redis-stunnel] connected remote server from 172.30.12.120:65484
2018.03.19 21:03:41 LOG4[229]: CERT: No matching host name found
2018.03.19 21:03:41 LOG4[229]: Rejected by CERT at depth=0: C=IN, ST=KARNATAKA, L=BANGALORE, O=AHC, OU=healthcare, CN=172.30.12.120
2018.03.19 21:03:41 LOG3[229]: SSL_connect: 14090086: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
2018.03.19 21:03:41 LOG5[229]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
```

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `checkHost = 172.30.12.28:6390` with `checkIP = 172.30.12.28`.

`checkHost` option checks if the specified DNS host name or wildcard matches any of those provided in peer certificate's SAN or CN fields.

To check against an IP address one has to use `checkIP` option.

Under the hood **stunnel** uses **OpenSSL**'s `X509_check_host` and `X509_check_ip_asc` functions. Here's their [description](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/X509_check_host.html).

Answer (score 0):

`checkHost = <value>` checks that the CN in the subject of the peer certificate corresponds to `<value>`. According to the log, the CN in the certificate is `172.30.12.120`. So you should change the client config to `checkHost = 172.30.12.120`.

This might make it work, although I'm not sure your TLS configuration is very well-thought.

It looks like you are not doing client side authentication, so you can remove `cert` from the client config. Also, if you have the server certificate on the client machine, you could use the "certificate pinning technique": remove the `checkHost` option and replace `verifyChain` with `verifyPeer = yes`. And `stunnel.pem` on the client machine must be the same as `stunnel.pem` on the server.

[Stunnel documentation contains some simple examples for this.](https://www.stunnel.org/auth.html)